# What derivative rule is applied here and how to see that it is?

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, economics, chain-rule

In order to calculate the marginal revenue, some derivative rules are applied, but I don't see which ones.

I don't think you need this, but this is given:
$Q = a-bP$ and $P = (a-Q)/b$
$\mbox{total revenue} = P\times Q = aP-bP^2$

and below the chain rule is applied, it seems, right?  But I can't get to see what parts of the formula of the chain rule correspond with the elements of the equation below.

$P$ and $Q$ can both be written as functions of each other but...

the solution I don't get: 
MO = marginal revenue = $ \frac{ \partial (P\times Q)} { \partial Q} = P \times \frac{\partial Q }{\partial Q} + Q \times \frac {\partial P} {\partial Q}$

My MathJax equation doesn't work for some reason, but /partial means the partial derivative, so the partial derivative of $P\times Q$ is calculated for $Q$ ...

Comment: Add a space after the word partial. And it's supposed to be a backslash.

Comment: As far as I could tell marginal revenue Is the derivative of the revenue function. Can you elaborate more on what's going on or your source?

Comment: Yes that is right, marginal revenue is the derivative of total revenue. That's also what's in the question. I think I have given all the relevant information. P and Q are both functions of each other. Basically P*Q is taken the partial derivative of to Q, not using the fact that it equals aP-bP^2. Maybe the total derivative is used? Or the chain rule? I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  revenue can be written as $R=P\cdot Q(\color{blue}P)=P\cdot (a-bP) $. Here you have to apply the $\textbf{product rule}$.  $Q$ depends on $P$ here.

$\text{First summand}$: The first factor $P$ is differentiated w.r.t $P$ and ismultiplied by the second factor $Q(P)$:

$$\frac{\partial P }{\partial P}\cdot Q(P)=1\cdot (a-bP)$$

$\text{Second summand}$: The second factor ($Q(P)$) is differentiated w.r.t $P$ and is multiplied by the first factor $P$:

$$\frac{\partial Q(P) }{\partial P}=-b\Rightarrow \frac{\partial Q(P) }{\partial P}\cdot P=-bP $$

The sum gives the marginal revenue:

$$MR=\frac{\partial P }{\partial P}\cdot Q(P)+\frac{\partial Q(P) }{\partial P}\cdot P=1\cdot (a-bP)-bP=a-2bP$$